# Deletion of Class / Trigger in PROD

Tags: deployment, production, visualstudiocode

I try to delete a trigger and a test class in prod. However, when I use the command:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -c -d destroy -w 20
```

I get the error:
[image]

Here my packages in the folder "destroy" directly under the Project root
[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: The only immediate suggestion I have is that the names are case sensitive. Make sure it's not `ProductsforProductGroup` or something like that. It must exactly match.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the hint! Worked well now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package.xml and destructiveChanges.xml (and in fact, pretty much the entire Metadata API) is case sensitive. Make sure the name of the trigger isn't `ProductsforProductGroup` or some other variation.